# Missing template in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular 2. I am developing I app that I completed the Root component that contains a navigation bar and footer. I am working on the homepage module right now and I am getting this error.

> [Error] Unhandled Promise rejection: (8)
>       Template parse errors:
>       site-header' is not a known element:
>       1. If 'site-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

This is my **main.ts** file in the homage folder

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-  dynamic';
import { HomepageModule } from './homepage.module';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(HomepageModule);
```

This is  the **module** file

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { HomepageComponent} from './homepage.component'
import { SiteHeaderComponent } from '../site-header/site-header.component'

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ SiteHeaderComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ HomepageComponent ]
})
export class HomepageModule { }
```

This is the content of the homepage template file

```
<site-header>header</site-header>
```

This is the contents of site-header html

```
<!-- Site header -->
<header class="site-header size-lg text-center" style="background-image: url(assets/img/bg-banner1.jpg)">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">


    </div>

  </div>
</header>
<!-- END Site header -->
```

I checked my imports multiple times and I do not see anything that looks off.

I even tried to restart the server maybe that was the issue.

Comment: Can you post your site header component?

Comment: I just added the code

Answer (score 0):

The HomepageComponent should be included in the declarations.  Bootstrap should only be used if this is the root module of your application.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [ 
                 HomepageComponent, 
                 SiteHeaderComponent 
  ]
})
export class HomepageModule { }
```

Comment: I don't have forms in the header yet because I plan on making the search form a component. So I can use it else were

Comment: Would I need to have the homepagecomponent declaration in the homepage module since I declare it already in the app module?

Comment: Your question led me to believe the HomepageModule was your root module, because you set the bootstrap property there.  You only need to set the bootstrap property one time in the root module of your application, in this case AppModule.  You're HomepageComponent should be registered in the declarations of the HomepageModule.  The HomepageModule should be registered in the Imports of your AppModule.